# Storing a Hash of Arrays into An Array?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, wrapper, pipe

I have to modify some Perl scripts for a piped run and write a wrapper script to run them with a given set of input parameters. Before I can do that, I have to understand what is going in the first program. I need help deciphering this code:

```
# declare and initialise an empty hash
my %to_keep= ();

# an array
@line = ('some\one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

# trim the identifier
$line[0]=~s/\/[1]$//;

# store this into an array
@{$to_keep{$line[0]}{'1'}}=($line[1],$line[2]);
print @;
```

I'm familiar with the perl substitute function, s///. It goes:

```
s/text-regex_to_be_replaced/replacement/modifier.
```

However, I'm not too sure what the code above is doing. If I understand correctly, it replaces every occurrence of of '\' with line[1], until the end of the string (indicated by the '$/'). Is this correct?

The other part I'm unsure about is the code below the 'store' comment. I think it's storing a hash of array into an array. Can someone explain how the code works and what it prints out given the variables? Also, how can I retrieve the data I store in the array?

Bonus question: Can someone explain how modifying a perl script for a piped run works?

thanks

Comment: Ummmmm....what would `print @;` accomplish?  Is that a typo?

Comment: The line $line[0] =~ s/\/[1]$//; looks arcane at best - why write [1] in stead of just 1?

Comment: To answer the first question, $line[0] =~ s/\/[1]$// removes the string /1 if it occurs at the end. It looks like a typing error - what it should read if replacing / at the end of the string with [1] was $line[0] =~ s/\//[1]/.

Comment: @JackManey I added in the `print @;` I would just like to know what is in the array. It's definitely a typo

Comment: @mzedeler `$line[0] =~ s/\/[1]$//;` isn't a typo. A postdoc in my lab wrote this code. He's not available at the moment so I can't ask him directly. I've sent him an email though.

Comment: @mzedeler thank you. `$line[0] =~ s/\/[1]$//;` does remove the string /1 if it occurs at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, this is wired.

```
s/\/[1]$//;
```

would will only match and remove /1 at the end of a string. So in your example it has no influence.

```
@{$to_keep{$line[0]}{'1'}}=($line[1],$line[2]);
```

broken down, on the left side you got
`$to_keep{'some\one'}{1}` which is undefined in the example! But if we say it would give you the value `foo`, then you take this value and replaces in to `@{foo}` which basically means use the value `foo` as the array name, hence `@foo`.

on the right side you save the second and third element of `$line` as a list into this  variable name, `@foo`.

If we ignore the undefined and try to guess the intention, you got a script that defines its own variable names. Using the first element of list as the variable name, and setting it equal to the rest of the list

Comment: I will try to apply your example to the actual code. thanks again